# Manipulate a function and a tangent

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I know that the tangent at `0` of `x Log [Abs [x]]` is `-Infinity`. But this is not clearly visible on the curve at the scale `x = -1` to `x = 1`.

Indeed, the convergence of the slope towards `-Infinity` is very slow.

I would really like to highlight this behavior thanks to an astute `PlotRange` coupled with a `Manipulate` which makes it possible to observe that the slope becomes infinite when looking at scales always.

I tried to do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[x *Log[Abs[x]], {x, (-10)^-k, 10^-k}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[x - 1, {x, (-10)^-k , 10^-k}], PlotRange -> All], {k, -5, 5}]
```

but it returns an error message.

Comment: Do you want to plot the function `f=x*Log[Abs[x]]` or its derivative / slope? I dont see the derivative in your plot command.

Comment: I want to study f=x*Log[Abs[x]] In the vicinity of 0

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(18090)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18090), [(119514)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119514). Related: [(19737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19737), [(a79760)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79760)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `-10^-k` rather than `(-10)^-k`:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[x*Log[Abs[x]], {x, -10^-k, 10^-k}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[x - 1, {x, -10^-k, 10^-k}], PlotRange -> All],
 {k, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Tangent plot]

But it might be better if you had legends:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{x*Log[Abs[x]], x - 1}, {x, -10^-k, 10^-k},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> {"x*Log[Abs[x]]", "x-1"}],
 {k, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Plot with legends]

However, to get the "feeling" that the slope is $-\infty$ at $x=0$, you want both axes to be on the same scale:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x*Log[Abs[x]], {x, -10^-k, 10^-k}, AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-10^-k, 10^-k}, {-10^-k, 10^-k}}],
 {k, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Even better display of slope at zero]

Comment: Thannnk you it'sperfect, I have been searching for a long time, Thanks a lot.Moreover, I am not sure, but I see that the slope becomes infinite when one looks at scales always smaller. Is ist a good impression ?

Comment: That's a good impression but that doesn't become as obvious if the axes are on different scales.  I've edited my answer to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x Log[-x], x < 0}, {x Log[x], x > 0}}]
der[p_] := D[f[u], u] /. u -> p
fun[p_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], D[f[x], x]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[{p, f[p]}], 
    Arrow[{{p, f[p]}, {p, f[p]} + Normalize[{1, der[p]}]}]}]
ListAnimate[Table[fun[j], {j, -2, 2, 0.12}]]
```

[image]